# Multiple arrays in one file in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

So I want my perl file to read a file that contains two lines:

```
1 10 4
6 4
```

I want the the first line to to be @setA and the second line @setB. How do I do that without hard coding it?

Comment: What do you have so far and why doesn't it fit your need? If you only have two lines, hardcoding it doesn't seem too bad. What issue are you trying to address?

Comment: I need to have to different arrays because eventually I have to compare them

Comment: You didn't answer about what you've tried...

Comment: when i starting learning perl, i read only one small book about it (not a classic lama book.) and this is the mmm first task you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $setA = <$fh>;   # "1 10 4"
my $setB = <$fh>;   # "6 4"
```

Or

```
my @setA = split ' ', scalar(<$fh>);   # ( 1, 10, 4 )
my @setB = split ' ', scalar(<$fh>);   # ( 6, 4 )
```

Answer (score 2):

You would open the file to obtain a so-called filehandle (typically named `$fh`), read the contents, and close the filehandle. Doing so involves calling [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), [`readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html), and [`close`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html).

Note readline also has a special syntax like `<$fh>`. Reading lines usually follows the idiom:

```
while ( <$fh> ) {
    # the line is in the $_ variable now
}
```

Then to tackle each line you'd use the [`split` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

Another one that is occasionally useful is [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html).

That should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie qw(:all);

open my $file, '<', 'file.txt';

my @lines = <$file>;
my @setA = $lines[0];
my @setB = $lines[1];

print("@setA");
print("@setB");

close $file;
```

Comment: Ouo! what are you trying to write here?

Comment: first: don't use `file` as filehandler, use `IO` or lexical `$filehandler`. second: use `<` for open file as read. third: kill all round brackets! it is perl! :) forth: why do you use diamond at the end? for __what__ reason?

Comment: But it works :) 1: I'm new in Perl,and his code is something simple. 2: Ok .3: I think this way is better for reading.4: Diamond at the end to wait for the user press a key.In my case,running by double-clicking the file :) Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: i don't said, that it fall down :) also use `unshift/shift` and `push/pop` functions for manage arrays